# RegEx: Removing equal sign

Tags: regex, nintex-workflow

I can remove the equal sign. however it is being replaced with a white space. How do I stop this from happening. I can't seem to get this simple operation working.

`A=12CD` is turning into `A 12CD` when I want `A12CD`

```
Pattern: =
Replacement Text: empty
Input Text: A=12CD
```

Comment: what is the replacement statement you are using?

Comment: I'm just leaving it empty

Comment: It is still leaving the space

Comment: What if you try a hack like `Pattern: =()` and `Replacement Text: $1`?

Comment: Any feedback? Does the hack work?

Comment: I will test tomorrow at work. Initially it did not work, however I think I typed something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There was a space and carriage return after the equal sign. I had to remove the space and carriage return before I could removed the equal sign.